# xcode 8.3.2 Bad Bundle Identifier, Invalid Code Signature Identifier, and Invalid Code Signing Entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, imessage-extension

This is my first time making an app. I'm getting no error messages in buildtime or runtime, but when I try to upload the app, I get the following errors:

> **Invalid Code Signing Entitlements**: Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'ABC.XXX.YYY.StickerPackExtension' for key 'application-identifier' in 'Payload/YYY.app/PlugIns/StickerPackExtension.appex/StickerPackExtension' is not supported. This value should be a string starting with your TEAMID, followed by a dot '.', followed by the bundle identifier.

The value is a bunch of numbers and letters, my TEAMID, the app name, and then the StickerPackExtension.

> **Invalid Code Signature Identifier**. The identifier "XXX.YYY.StickerPackExtension" in your code signature for "StickerPackExtension" must match its Bundle Identifier "XXX.YYY"

When I change the identifier to be the same as its Bundle Identifier, I get another error message telling me that they cannot be the same.

> **Bad Bundle Identifier**. The bundle identifier 'XXX.YYY' of the application extension YYY.app/PlugIns/StickerPackExtension.appex should start with the application's bundle identifier 'XXX.YYY' and not contain more than one period "." after the application's bundle ID.

I have no idea what to do with this.

I've searched on here and elsewhere a bunch, but I'm hitting a brick wall! Not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

If your app bundleId format is : **com.abc.app**

Than your app extension bundleID should be : **com.abc.app.XXX**

*Creating new appID and provisioning profile it will fix the issue*